# Score of two vectors extracted haris MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matching, feature-extraction

I have two vectors of matched features extracted from two palmprints images using :

```
I1 = imread('PolyU_001_F_08.bmp');
I2 =  imread('PolyU_001_F_01.bmp' );
points1 = detectHarrisFeatures(I1);
points2 = detectHarrisFeatures(I2);
[features1,valid_points1] = extractFeatures(I1,points1);
[features2,valid_points2] = extractFeatures(I2,points2);
indexPairs = matchFeatures(features1,features2);
matchedPoints1 = valid_points1(indexPairs(:,1),:);
matchedPoints2 = valid_points2(indexPairs(:,2),:);
```

How could i have the final score of similarity between the two vectors so i can decide based on threshold if it is a match or not.

Answer (score 0):

After feature matching you need to apply some transformation model(using RANSAC or MSAC), and this will give you a measure  of quality:

```
[tform,inlierPtsDistorted,inlierPtsOriginal] =  estimateGeometricTransform(matchedPoints1,matchedPoints2,'similarity');
xoffset=tform.T(3,1);
yoffset=tform.T(3,2);
```

Comment: is there a way to find the range of the distance or do i have to loop all images of the data base?

Comment: You must give more details on the problem. The range of distance of what?

Comment: I mean i want to know the min and the max of the distance between the two vectors so i can choose a thresholds to draw the ROC curve.  For fingerprint (minutiae based ) for example the scores of similarity range is between 0 and 1 so the problem is easy, but in distance related i have extracted features using different methods (pca, dct BNP., cont code ..etc) it seems that the distance is different each time, sorry because it is a new subject to me. thanks

Comment: You mean to this distance? 'sqrt(sum((matchedPoints1.Location-matchedPoints2.Location)'.^2))'

Comment: Yes this distance,  how could I know the range of this distance.

Comment: you can use 'prctile(dist,5)' and 'prctile(dist,95)', but the best is to use the values in matrix 'tform.T' that output from 'estimateGeometricTransform'. the last row give you the x distance and y distance.